# Heroku deployment - RoR - "Detected manifest file, assuming assets were compiled locally"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, web-config

RoR rookie here with a small issue regarding Heroku deployment. Asset pipeline is not getting compiled when I deploy to Heroku. I tried a lot of suggestions available online but with no success. In my build, I see "Detected manifest file, assuming assets were compiled locally" message and my page loads with aplication.js and application.css throwing below error.

```
http://*masked-app-name*/assets/application-ae1bb08c08ec882f8d7005ca99addcfef89e47173e0ba1971862de4357d10918.js 
  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

**Production.rb**

```
CareForMe::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true  
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local = false  
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true  
  config.serve_static_assets = true
  config.assets.compress = true  
  config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(:beautify => true) if defined? Uglifier   
  config.assets.compile = true   
  config.assets.digest = true   
  config.assets.version = '1.0'   
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true   
  config.log_level = :debug 
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true   
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify   
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new 
end
```

**application.rb**

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)
require "active_record/railtie" require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie" require "sprockets/railtie"
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)
module CareForMe   
  class Application < Rails::Application
  end 
end
```

Any inputs are much appreciated. My apologies if this is repeat question but I have not been successful so far with all the tries that I did with online information. :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem before. All I did was add this to my `config/application.rb`

`config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false`

Comment: Ha! Solved the problem. Thank you so much!!

Comment: The config.assets.initialize_on_precompile option has been **removed** is and not needed for Rails 4.